# Param converter (routing) sets optional variable to some value which should be null

Tags: symfony

I've got following route declaration

```php
/**
 * @Route("/{section}/entries/{entry}", name="entries_list")
 * @param Section $section
 * @param Entry|null $entry
 */
public function entries_list(Section $section, Entry $entry = null)
{
    dd($section, $entry);
}
```

When I enter the following url: /6/entries somehow param converter sets the `$entry` variable to:

```
App\Entity\Entry {#3987 ▼
  -id: 1
```

Why it's not a `null`? I hadn't set any default value to 1. `$section` variable is set correctly.

When I try to enter the url: /6/entries/0 I've got `$entry` set to `null` as there is no such record in Database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug / unwanted behaviour in SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.

`Section` can have many `Entries` and `DoctrineParamConverter` class searches using criteria and loads first `entry` related to `section` with id `6`. However if I explicitly set `null` in my request, there shouldn't be any additional search triggered.

To make it works as expected I needed to force that class to search only by ID:

```php
* @Route("/{id}/entries/{entry}", name="entries_list")
* @ParamConverter("entry", options={"id": "entry"})
```